# Transferring raw binary instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, binary, typed-arrays

All we know that sending **raw binary** instead of **JSON** between client and server (exactly web browser and web server) pretty reduce the usage of bandwidth and increase the speed of transferring data, but as we see, all popular web based system(s) still uses **JSON**. *Gmail, Google Plus, Facebook, Linkedin and...*
Nowaday, we have `Typed Array` in JavaScript that makes parsing binary data really easy and fast.

Currently I'm going to develop a web-based financial system and I think using **raw binary** makes system so much faster than **JSON**.

I want to know **WHY** those popular web-based systems didn't use **raw binary** instead of **JSON** for transferring data between client and server? Is there any technical reason that I don't know?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you benchmarked JSON vs. raw binary? Raw binary probably would reduce bandwidth, but probably would not reduce latency. How big are the responses? Would anyone notice if you reduced a 1k response to 600 bytes?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I didn't compare them really in production environment and you're correct about latency, there's no difference.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I have a lot of messages (about 30 messages per second for each client) but they don't have a big size, maximum is 1kb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typed Arrays are a recent thing and have not historically been supported by the many browsers out there. When you want your products used by as many people as possible you're going to choose the most common denominator.

This is not to say that in future, these systems won't move towards using such an approach, but not until it's supported by the majority.

Comment: Short and simple, market compatibility. +1

Answer (score 4):

Endianness issues would be one reason. Flexibility is another, with binary your packet format is fixed so you need to get it right first time, with things like JSON there's no strict ordering of fields and you can add new ones without breaking compatibilty (doesn't apply to removing them).

Comment: Sure yes, maintaining the raw binary is much harder than json.

Answer (score 1):

Browser compatibility (mainly IE). Check out Caniuse Typed Arrays: http://caniuse.com/typedarrays